# PuPHPet Vagrant configuration doesn't sync with the good folder

Tags: vagrant, rsync

I'm new with vagrant so i tried to use puphpet for configure my VM

But i don't understand why my folder doesn't sync with my /var/www of my VM.
But i see when i update or change something in my folder machine in /vagrant folder of my VM is sync.

Can you tell me how to do for synced the /var/www/html like /vagrant is synced in my VM?

This my config.yml of puphpet for sync folders:

```yaml
synced_folder:
            vflsf_mny3nbub9zel:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: rsync
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
```

Thanks very much and sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the host machine where the Vagrantfile is *(indicated by 'source' in your config.yaml)*:

`$ vagrant rsync-auto`

This will sync added/changed files from the host machine to the guest vm.